# Passing arguments to application

Tags: c#, wpf, process, command-line-arguments, app-startup

This question might seem a bit vague but here we go.

I am preventing multiple instances of my wpf application, like so:

```
Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
if (Process.GetProcessesByName(proc.ProcessName).Length > 1)
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
    return;
}

if (e.Args != null && e.Args.Count() > 0)
{
    this.Properties["Magnet"] = e.Args;
}
```

Is it possible to pass the command-line arguments to the application already running?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793997/pass-arguments-to-running-application) will help.

Comment: We use WCF (mentioned in some of the links already posted, so I won't relink). WCF is fiddly to use at first, but it is (IMHO) the best way to do this kind of interprocess communications.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541354/simple-communication-between-2-instances-of-application

Comment: Thanks for all the great comments and answers, been of great services. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. You should use some of [inter process communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153/interprocess-communication-for-windows-in-c-sharp-net-2-0) techniques.

Comment: Yes, it is possible solution - named pipes, remoting, etc

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested in, I decided to use this code in my App.Xaml.cs:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    if (SingleInstance<App>.InitializeAsFirstInstance(UNIQUE))
    {
        var application = new App();
        application.InitializeComponent();
        application.Run();
        SingleInstance<App>.Cleanup();
    }
}

public bool SignalExternalCommandLineArgs(IList<string> args)
{
    // Use arguments
    return true;
}
```

UNIQUE is a constant string of 20 characters.

`SingleInstance<App>.Cleanup()` derives from `ISingleInstanceApp` which is defined in [`SingleInstance.cs`](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/SingleInstance.cs.txt) and I also implemented `ISingleInstanceApp` in my application class.

Thanks for all the help!